# C# Bitmap GetPixel(), SetPixel() in GPU

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, gpgpu, cudafy.net

I am using Cudafy as c# wrapper 
I need to get colour info `InputBitmap0.GetPixel(x, y)` of a bitmap and make an new bitmap for output .

I need the following work to be done in GPU.

**IN CPU**

```
OutputBitmap.SetPixel(object_point_x, object_point_y, InputBitmap0.GetPixel(x, y));
```

**In short:**

How to GetPixel() for each pixel point of the input Bitmap, SetPixel() for each pixel point of the outputbitmap Bitmap in GPU.

Comment: this question is way too broad as written and I have voted to close it as such

Comment: @talonmies I have tried to be detailed so that contributors can understand it easily! Instead of closing it down can I get to learn one possible way of solving it?

Comment: You haven't asked a serious question here. What *exactly* do you what to know? CUDA doesn't have native C# bindings and you have not  even said what framework you are using. Do you understand the bit map data format? Have you tried actually writing a kernel? What is the problem if you have? That is why this is too broad. You have posted a wish list, not a [SO] question

Comment: @talonmies thnx for your response! I have narrowed down my question! Can you please help now?

Comment: I believe CUDAfy.NET targers mostly non-graphics related intensive numeric operations, while you're looking at graphics operations, served by CUDA's NPP https://developer.nvidia.com/npp (which doesn't seem to be supported by CUDAfy.NET)

Comment: @Md.Sifatul Islam, you can try to play with pixel shader in MonoGame.

Comment: @SeNS thnx buddy solved my problem!

Comment: @Md.Sifatul Islam, should I post an answer to get bounty points? Could you provide code snippet for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> OutputBitmap.SetPixel(object_point_x, object_point_y, InputBitmap0.GetPixel(x, y))

It took time but finally, I , cracked my case.

We have two `Bitmap` : one for output `OutputBitmap` and another for input `InputBitmap0`

Lets divide this task into parts:

1. do `InputBitmap0.GetPixel()` for `x` ,`y` coordinate
2. then , `OutputBitmap.SetPixel()` for a different coordinate `object_point_x, object_point_y`

Cudafy does not support `Bitmap` or `Color` type data. So I converted the Bitmaps to `byte` type.

```
BitmapData InputBitmapData0 = InputBitmap0.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, InputBitmap0.Width, InputBitmap0.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

IntPtr ptr0 = InputBitmapData0.Scan0;//pointer for color

int stride0 = InputBitmapData0.Stride;

byte[]  input_ragba_color = new byte[InputBitmapData0.Stride * InputBitmap0.Height];

Marshal.Copy(ptr0, input_ragba_color, 0, bytes0);// Copy the RGB values of color value into the array.
```

We have copied the content of the `InputBitmap0` to the `rgbValues` array. Now we need to do the work of `GetPixel()` (get the values of R,G,B,A).

We need to do the above work ( make array) for `OutputBitmap` too because we will be doing `SetPixel()` in GPU but we will copy the array back to the bitmap later.

```
BitmapData OutputBitmapData = OutputBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, OutputBitmap.Width, OutputBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, OutputBitmap.PixelFormat);
IntPtr ptr_output = OutputBitmapData.Scan0;

byte[] output_ragba = new byte[OutputBitmapData.Stride * OutputBitmap.Height];
```

Its GPU time for calculation. Lets initialize gpu.

```
CudafyModule km = new CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();
GPGPU gpu = new CudafyHost.getDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);
gpu.LoadModule(km);
```

Now send `input_ragba_color` and `output_ragba` to the gpu because we can iterate the array and do any calculation.

```
byte[] dev_output_rgba_color = gpu.Allocate<byte>(output_ragba.Length);
byte[] dev_input_ragba_color = gpu.CopyToDevice(input_ragba_color);
gpu.Launch(N, 1).update_bitmap(x, y, object_point_x, object_point_y,int stride0, int OutputBitmapData.Stride,dev_input_ragba_color,dev_output_rgba_color);
```

**Now inside GPU(kernel)**

```
[Cudafy]
public static void update_bitmap(GThread thread, int x,int y,int object_point_x,int  object_point_y,int stride0, int OutputBitmapData_Stride,byte [] dev_input_ragba_color,byte [] dev_output_rgba_color)
{
   dev_output_rgba_color[(object_point_y * OutputBitmapData_Stride) + (object_point_x * 4)] = input_ragba_color[(y * stride0) + (x * 4)];  
   dev_output_rgba_color[(object_point_y * OutputBitmapData_Stride) + (object_point_x * 4) + 1] = input_ragba_color[(y * stride0) + (x * 4) + 1];
   dev_output_rgba_color[(object_point_y * OutputBitmapData_Stride) + (object_point_x * 4) + 2] = input_ragba_color[(y * stride0) + (x * 4) + 2];
   dev_output_rgba_color[(object_point_y * OutputBitmapData_Stride) + (object_point_x * 4) + 3] = input_ragba_color[(y * stride0) + (x * 4) + 3];

}
```

> I am taking values of each R,G,B,A ,ex: `input_ragba_color[(y *
>   stride0) + (x * 4) + 1]` which is solving 1st task
>   (`InputBitmap0.GetPixel()`)
>
> `dev_output_rgba_color` is taking the values of `input_ragba_color`
>   example:
>
> ```
> dev_output_rgba_color[(object_point_y * OutputBitmapData_Stride) + (object_point_x * 4)] = input_ragba_color[(y * stride0) + (x * 4)];
> ```
>
> which is solves our 2nd task (`OutputBitmap.SetPixel()`)

We now know that gpu has populated an array(`dev_output_rgba_color`) for our `OutputBitmap`.

```
gpu.CopyFromDevice(dev_output_rgba_color, output_ragba);   //dev_output_rgba_color values will be assigned to output_ragba
gpu.FreeAll();
```

Copy the result back to the `OutputBitmap` using the memory pointer and unlock it from the memory.

```
Marshal.Copy(output_ragba, 0, ptr_output, output_bytes);// Copy the RGB values of color value into the array.
OutputBitmap.UnlockBits(OutputBitmapData);
```

Now the `OutputBitmap` contains the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use a `byte[]` and allocate that on the GPU. [I've seen you asking around](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/992064/bitmap-in-cudafy/) and this answer is a work in progress, I'll keep updating it over the next few days as I get time.

```
CudafyModule km = new CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();
GPGPU gpu = new CudafyHost.getDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);
gpu.LoadModule(km);

var image = new Bitmap(width, height);
image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\temp\a.bmp", true);
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[width * height * 4];
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, format);
    imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
byte[] device_imageBytes = _gpu.CopyToDevice(imageBytes);

byte r = 0;
byte g = 0;
byte b = 0;

byte device_r = _gpu.Allocate<byte>(r);
byte device_g = _gpu.Allocate<byte>(g);
byte device_b = _gpu.Allocate<byte>(b);

//Call this in a loop
gpu.Launch(N, 1).GetPixel(x, y, device_imageBytes, device_r, device_g, device_b);

...

[Cudafy]
public static void GetPixel(GThread thread, int x, int y, byte[] imageBytes, byte blue, byte green, byte red)
{
    int offset = x * BPP + y * stride;
    blue = imageBytes[offset++];
    green = imageBytes[offset++];
    red = imageBytes[offset];

    double R = red;
    double G = green * 255;
    double B = blue * 255 * 255;

}
```